# "The name does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get the following error;
The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace Exchange101
{
    // This sample is for demonstration purposes only. Before you run this sample, make sure that the code meets the coding requirements of your organization.
    class Ex15_CreateMeetingOnBehalfOfPrinciple_CS
    {
        static ExchangeService service = Service.ConnectToService(UserDataFromConsole.GetUserData(), new TraceListener());
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var request = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["source"];
            HttpRequest q = Request;
            NameValueCollection n = q.QueryString;
            if (n.HasKeys())
            {
                string k = n.GetKey(0);
                if (k == "one")
                {
                    string v = n.Get(0);
                }
                if (k == "two")
                {
                    string v = n.Get(0);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm an absolute newbie and have researched the error but am confused as to which assembly I might be missing as a reference.

Comment: If this is the code behind a webpage, it should extend the class `System.Web.UI.Page`.

Comment: I truly wish I knew what that meant.

Comment: Are you referencing System.Web?

Comment: I wasn't until I decided to add code to get the url params.

Comment: Oh, yeah, mellamokb probably has it right. Variable names in C# are case sensitive.

Comment: It is confusing that you have a class with `Page_Load`, but it is not a `Page` object itself.  Did you copy this code from some example project?

Comment: It was an example of adding a meeting to an Exchange calendar via EWS API. I wanted to mess with the code to take out the console input for an email address and password.  I want to call this page from another page passing the variables.

Comment: I'm getting the same context error on the following line for UserData;
Mailbox principle = new Mailbox(UserData.EmailAddress);

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @user990016 check my answer, may be it will solve your issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

issue may be here

```
 var request = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["source"];
 HttpRequest q = Request;
```

your variable name is **request** bt you are using **Request**

change this as

```
 var request = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["source"];
 HttpRequest q = request;
```

this wil solve your issue

Comment: Or even "HttpRequest q = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["source"];"

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
class Ex15_CreateMeetingOnBehalfOfPrinciple_CS
```

to this:

```
class Ex15_CreateMeetingOnBehalfOfPrinciple_CS : System.Web.UI.Page
```

It looks like the problems you're getting are from properties you should be inheriting from that class.

Answer (score -1):

If you are meaning HttpWebRequest, you should include the namespace 
    using System.Net;

Comment: Doesn't HttpRequest just live in System.Web?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest%28v=vs.100%29.aspx Says namespace System.Web.